# Im getting unexpectected token : for a valid JSON

Tags: json, dojo, esri, arcgis-js-api

I am working with ArcGIS, Esri request and I am trying to get a data from a webserver, but everytime I got the same "unexpected token : " error even when my response is correct.

Thanks in advance.

Here's my code:

```
require(["dojo/dom", "dojo/on", "dojo/dom-class", "dojo/_base/json",  "esri/urlUtils", "esri/config", "esri/request", "dojo/domReady!"], function(dom, on, domClass, dojoJson, urlUtils, esriConfig, esriRequest) {

    // fallback to proxy for non-CORS capable browsers
    // esri.config.defaults.io.proxyUrl  =  "/arcgisserver/apis/javascript/proxy/proxy.ashx";
    esriConfig.defaults.io.proxyUrl = "/proxy/proxy.ashx";

    dom.byId("url").value = "http://api.citybik.es/v2/networks/dublinbikes";
    dom.byId("content").value = "";

    //handle the Go button's click event
    on(dom.byId("submitRequest"), "click", getContent);

    function getContent(){

      var contentDiv = dom.byId("content");
      contentDiv.value = "";
      domClass.remove(contentDiv, "failure");
      dom.byId("status").innerHTML = "Downloading...";

     //  //get the url 
     // var url = urlUtils.urlToObject(dom.byId("url").value);

     //  console.log("EL URL path",url.path)
     //  console.log("EL URL query",url.query)
     //  var requestHandle = esriRequest({
     //    "url": url.path,
     //    "content": url.query
     //  });
     //  requestHandle.then(requestSucceeded, requestFailed);

      function requestSucceeded(data) {
        console.log(data);
      }

      function requestFailed(error) {
        console.log("Error: ", error.message);
      }

      var request = esriRequest({
        url: "http://api.citybik.es/v2/networks/dublinbikes",
        content: {
          format:  "json"
        },
        handleAs: "json",
        callbackParamName: "retrive"
      });
      request.then(requestSucceeded, requestFailed);
    }
  }
);
```

Im getting:

> Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token :                                  dublinbikes:2

Comment: Is your `callbackParamName` correct? Looks like it could be misspelled

Comment: @Shoe That should only affect the JSONP response (ie. it should be the name of the 'variable' that the server sends back as JSONP) - I feel like there's a problem somewhere between `content: {format: "json"}`, the fact that @gabolop has a proxy specified and whether that proxy is a) being invoked, or b) behaving itself.

Comment: I'm not convinced [v2 of the CityBikes API](http://api.citybik.es/v2/) actually supports JSONP...?

Answer (score 2):

The root problem is that you're getting `esri.request` a bit confused with what you're asking for, and what the server is giving back. Because you're making a request on a different domain (`api.citybik.es`) from where you're running the code (whatever your host is), you need to use either:

- CORS
- JSONP
- a proxy

to get around the browser's security restrictions. There's plenty of detail on SO about these, I won't dribble on further.

Your code has two methods configured - the `callbackParamName` tells `esri.request` to use JSONP, and you've also got a proxy set just in case. The `callbackParamName` tells it to only use JSONP though, so the proxy is ignored.

Now the real problem, as I noted in a comment above, is that v2 of the [CityBikes API](http://api.citybik.es/v2/) doesn't actually seem to support JSONP, so your callback parameter is ignored and the server gives you back straight JSON. `esri.request` is expecting JSONP, and voila - unexpected token `:`. Requesting

http://api.citybik.es/v2/networks/dublinbikes?callback=stackoverflow

returns:

```
{
network: {
company: "JCDecaux",
href: "/v2/networks/dublinbikes",
....
```

See? No mention of our `stackoverflow` variable. If you look at [v1 of the API](http://api.citybik.es/) instead, that DOES support JSONP. Requesting

http://api.citybik.es/dublinbikes.json?callback=stackoverflow

returns:

```
stackoverflow(
[
{
bikes: 1,
name: "Fenian Street",
idx: 0,
....
```

...and there is our `stackoverflow` variable. OR you can remove the `callbackParamName` from your `esriRequest`, and see if your proxy will process the JSON from the v2 address.